# Escaped Characters Outside the Basic Multilingual Plane (BMP) in Prolog

Tags: unicode, prolog, swi-prolog, unicode-escapes, iso-prolog

For reference, I'm using Prolog v7.4.2 on Windows 10, 64-bit

Entering the following code in the REPL:

```
write("\U0001D7F6"). % Mathematical Monospace Digit Zero
```

gives me this error in the output:

```
ERROR: Syntax error: Illegal character code
ERROR: write("
ERROR: ** here **
ERROR: \U0001D7F6") .
```

I know for a fact that U+1D7F6 is a valid Unicode character, so what's up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SWI-Prolog internally uses C `wchar_t` to represent Unicode characters.  On Windows these are 16 bit and intended to hold UTF-16 encoded strings.  SWI-Prolog however uses `wchar_t` to get nice arrays of code points and thus effectively only supports UCS-2 on Windows (code points `u0000..uffff`).

On non-Windows systems, `wchar_t` is usually 32 bits and thus the complete Unicode range is supported.

It is not a trivial thing to fix as handling `wchar_t` as UTF-16 looses the nice property that each element of the array is exactly one code point and using our own 32-bit type means we cannot use the C library wide character functions and have to reimplement them in SWI-Prolog.  This is not only work, but replacing them with pure C versions also looses the optimization typically present in modern C runtime libraries.

Answer (score 2):

The ISO core standard syntax for char codes looks different. The following works in SICStus Prolog, Jekejeke Prolog, SWI-Prolog, etc.. for example, and is thus more portable:

Using SWI-Prolog on a Mac:

```
Welcome to SWI-Prolog (threaded, 64 bits, version 7.5.8)
SWI-Prolog comes with ABSOLUTELY NO WARRANTY. This is free software.

?- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, codes).
true.

?- X = "\x1D7F6\".
X = [120822].

?- write('\x1D7F6\'), nl.
```

And Jekejeke Prolog on a Mac:

```
Jekejeke Prolog 2, Runtime Library 1.2.2
(c) 1985-2017, XLOG Technologies GmbH, Switzerland

?- X = "\x1D7F6\".
X = [120822]

?- write('\x1D7F6\'), nl.
```

The underlying syntax is found in the ISO core standard at section 6.4.2.1 hexadecimal escape sequence. It reads as follows and is shorter than the U-syntax:

```
hex_esc_seq --> "\x" hex_digit { hex_digit } "\".
```

Answer (score 1):

For comparison, I get:

```
?- write('\U0001D7F6').
```

What is your environment and what do the flags say?

For example:

```
$ set | grep LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
```

and also:

```
?- current_prolog_flag(encoding, F).
F = utf8.
```

Comment: my encoding is, evidently, "text". How do I tell prolog to use UTF-8?

Comment: See the help on [**encoding**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=encoding) and also [`set_stream/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=set_stream/2). You probably need to set some environment variables or equivalent configuration.

Comment: You are using the terminal stream.

Comment: How do you refer to the terminal stream then?

Comment: Please see the section about [**encoding**](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=encoding) and also [`set_stream/2`](http://eu.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?predicate=set_stream/2). In particular, the aliases `current_input` and `current_output` may be important for your case. It may help to use for example `?- set_stream(current_input, encoding(utf8)).` and `?- set_stream(current_output, encoding(utf8)).`, but I can only guess at this point.

Comment: Okay, I tried that and it doesn't make a difference. I still get complaints about illegal character codes.

Comment: It reports a _syntax error_ during _read_.  If you run this code on a Unix system with a _locale_ that cannot represent this character, reading is fine but _writing_ will raise an I/O error (not on the terminal; there the value is escaped).